# In how many ways can we distribute $k$ identical objects to $n$ distinct recipients so that each recipient gets at least $m$?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we distribute $k$ identical objects to $n$ distinct
recipients so that each recipient gets at least $m$?

The answer I got is different than the one in the answer key, I'll explain how I got my answer what what the answer key in the book is, can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

My answer: distributing $k$ identical objects to $n$ distinct people so that each person gets at least $m$ is the same thing as giving each person $m$ objects than distributing the rest ($k-mn$) of the objects to $n$ people.
We have $k-nm$ objects and $n-1$ dividers, so now we have ($k-mn$)+($n-1$) slots, we have to place the dividers in ($n-1$) of these slots and the objects in the remaining slots.
Now all we have to do is count how many ways we can choose to place the $n-1$ dividers among the ($k-mn$)+($n-1$) slots, this is ${k-mn+n-1 \choose n-1}$
But the answer key says ${n+k-mn+1 \choose k-mn}$ or ${k-(m-1)n+1 \choose n+1}$

I tried using numbers to see if my answer and the books answers are equivalent and it does not look like they are, unless I made a mistake.
Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong?

Comment: I think what you got is correct. I came to the same conclusion when distributing $m-1$ objects to $n$ recipients first, then put in $n-1$ dividers in $(k-(m-1)n-1)$ slots. Also, consider the simple problem when you have 5 objects and want to distribute to 2 people, each has at least 1. Your formula works. Possibly a typo in the book (they need $-1$ instead of $+1$)

Comment: The book’s answer is either a consistent typo or a mental hiccup on someone’s part; yours is correct.